# Event for change input type color JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get new color on input type=color, if I use jquery it's working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colorPicker = $('.input-color');

        colorPicker.on("change", function watchColorPicker() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $(".title").each(function() {
                $(this).css({'color' : val});
            });
        });
});
```

But I don't know, how write on native js.
The error is .change or .on is not a function

```
window.onload = function(){

    var colorPicker = document.getElementsByClassName('input-color');
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

    function colorChange(color) {
        for(var j =0; j < color.length; j++) {

            color[j].addEventListener('change', function () {
                var newColor = this.value;

                for(var i =0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    text[i].style.color = newColor;
                }
            })
        }
    }

    colorChange(colorPicker);
};
```

Comment: *"how write on native js"* DOM, not "native js." You want to use the DOM directly, rather than using the DOM via jQuery. The **language** is JavaScript regardless.

Comment: That code certainly looks like it should work. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: ...and in fact, it does: https://jsfiddle.net/ts4t9m1n/

Answer (score 4):

I've compressed your pure js code a little bit, looks clean and light. Also reduced the number of loops.

```js
const colorPicker = document.querySelector('#input-color');
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

colorPicker.addEventListener('change', function() {
  Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.style.color = this.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="input-color" type='color' />
<p class='title'>First</p>
<p class='title'>Second</p>
<p class='title'>Third</p>
```